# Is there a way to close the browser using googlescript or javascript, by just clicking a button for it?

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

I have an application that I developed in AppMaker. I call the link of this app from a native android app . I am trying to make a button in the appmaker environment, in order to be able to close the browser when that button is clicked.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works in AppMaker but you could try `window.close();`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `window.close()` directly otherwise sometimes you may get errors like *`Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.`*

So here the first line of code is doing magic. It is opening `nothing` (first argument) and second argument i.e '_self' specifying to open in same page.

```
window.open('', '_self', ''); 
window.close();
```

Comment: Code-only answers like this are usually best explained with a little more information, otherwise they tend to be deleted. Could you expand this please?